Create a custom store listing to customize name, description and logo based on the region
I have a requirement to publish one app to multiple regions. However, I want the name, description and the logo of the application to be different in each regions.
For example
UAE app name - xxx
KSA app name - yyy
I found this documentation from google suggesting that this is possible.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9867158?hl=en#zippy=%2Cwhat-you-can-customize%2Ctargeting-via-a-unique-custom-store-listing-url%2Ccountry-targeting
However, Its not possible for me to test this without actually uploading a live app and go through a review.
Questions -

What is the level of customization that can be achieved?
Region based custom listing - Is it dependent on the users play store region?
Is it possible to do the same thing in iOS app store?


1.On Store presence -> Store listing press on the manage translations.
this will let enter same details for different languages.
2.It depends on their google user region , when they created a user and states the region , country , address etc.
3.Apple Store collects the locale from your app configuration.
